# Telerik radgridview cell co-ordinates in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I want to show a specific date time picker control on a particular cell in Telerik RadGridView in C# Windows form. For this I need to know the co-ordinates of that particular cell relative to that form. I don't want to set the full column to DateTimePicker since the datatype won't be fixed for all the rows of that particular column. How can I retrieve the current cell co-ordinates so that I can show a separate DataTimePicker control at that position?

Answer (score 0):

RadGridView uses editors for its cells. To achieve your scenario you should create a custom editor and assign this editor in the EditorRequired event for the particular cell. Here is an article from the Telerik UI for WinForms documentation which says how you can create and use custom editor: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-editors-using-custom-editors.html